# Как расширить карту google на весь экран

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps

Есть карта google map использую стандартный скрипт для вывода карты с маркерами. Но создал еще одну кнопку для развертывания на весь экран карты, сделал событие клика и хочу развернуть, но не знаю как это сделать. Может есть событие для развертывания на весь экран в api google map?

Comment: покажите контейнер вашей карты. И код как вы сделали этот "на вес экран"

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите тут: http://www.doogal.co.uk/FullScreen.php
Необходимо подключить скрипт, описывающий control для развёртывания карты на весь экран и добавить control на карту.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).